# How to explain the word "shadow "as a noun?

Tags: nouns, parts-of-speech

We often say that the name of a person, place or thing is called noun. So, in which category, we include "shadow" as a noun. Though it is neither a place nor a thing or person.

Comment: "Person, place or thing" is a rather limited list that is offered to people when they first start learning a language. Nouns can also be used about abstract concepts, like emotions, and even things that, by definition, don't exist, like 'absence'. Shadow is something that is defined by the absence of light, so it's a not-thing.

Comment: So, what will be the proper definition to cover all these things?

Comment: [Noun](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noun): any member of a class of words that typically can ... refer to an entity, quality, state, action, or **concept**.

Comment: If a "thing" has to be only an object or an item that we can touch or see, how can we tell people to "do the right thing"?

Comment: Every language that I'm familiar with has a noun meaning "shadow". I think you are misunderstanding what a "noun" is. For example, in your sentence the word "category" is a noun. The name of a specific person, place or thing would be a **proper noun**.

Comment: @JavaLatte That would have been useful as an answer but is just tepid air in a comment on a closed question that could have been useful for other readers but is not just taking up internet storage.

Comment: Agreed, @Araucaria. But I was a newbie back then and hadn't really got a clear idea about what constituted a useful answer and what was appropriate for a comment.

Comment: @JavaLatte Well, if we could get the question reopened you could convert your comment into an answer!

Comment: @JavaLatte You could write a decent and useful answer now! I would try to write one, but am going on holiday in half an hour (and haven't finished my work for uni yet ...).

Answer (score 5):

Shadow is an [abstract noun](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/Abstract-Nouns.html). Various definitions of ['shadow'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shadow) as a noun are given here.

Feelings and  intangible things are included in the category of abstract noun. 'Light' is also an abstract noun as we can't touch it.

Comment: I'd classify *light* as a *concrete noun*, not an *abstract noun* because we can interact physically with light. (See this more concise definition of an [abstract noun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abstract-noun?q=abstract+noun)).

Answer (score 1):

"Person, place or thing" is a rather limited list that is offered to people when they first start learning a language. Some people refer to this list as **concrete nouns** one definition "something material": another is [things that you can experience through your five senses: sight, smell, hearing, taste, and touch](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/concrete-noun.html). A more up-to-date definition would probably include things that you can measure using the appropriate equipment, for example electricity, magnetism and weight.

There are also nouns for abstract concepts like justice, love and truth: we call these **abstract nouns**.

We also have nouns for things that, by definition, are nothing, like 'absence' and 'vacuum'.

Shadow is something that is defined by the absence of light, so it's a not-thing. You can see light and you can see a shadow, so it's a **concrete noun**.